# positive Harris recurrent, aperiodic, stationary Markov chain

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains, mixing

How to proof that every positive Harris recurrent, aperiodic, stationary Markov chain is alpha-mixing (strong-mixing)?

Answer (score 3):

In the following, all results are referenced from Bradley (2005).

Suppose that $X := (X_k, k \in \mathbb{Z})$ is a strictly stationary Markov chain. If $X$ is Harris recurrent and aperiodic then $X$ is $\beta$-mixing
(Theorem 3.5), and hence $\alpha$-mixing (Section 2.1 or Theorem 3.2).

## References

Bradley, Richard C. (2005), [Basic Properties of Strong Mixing Conditions. A Survey and Some Open Questions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0511078.pdf). *Probability Surveys* 2, 107-144. doi: 10.1214/154957805100000104